# Java's int read(byte[] data) returns more bytes than expected

Tags: java, input, stream, return-value

I wrote a simple program to test the read() method and I noticed that I am having different values of the number of bytes read than expected. Here is the program:

```
class ReadBytes {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
  byte[] data = new byte[10];

  System.out.println("Read some characters.");
  System.out.println("You have read " + System.in.read(data) + " bytes.");
  System.out.print("You wrote: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   System.out.print((char) data[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Now my problem is in the output of the 2nd println. When i just press enter without any other characters inserted, the output is:

> Read some characters.
>
> You have read **2** bytes.
>
> You wrote:

I was expecting "*You have read **0** bytes.*"

In fact for every character I type up to 8, I get *(bytes expected + 2)*, for more than 8 characters, I get a value of 10.

Can someone explain me the meaning of those additional 2 bytes?

Thank you for your time to read this and help me.

Comment: If you're windows isn't it the `\r\n` for the line separator? Thus the two extra bytes  when you pressed the enter key.

Comment: This will be \r\n. Carrage return+line feed.

Comment: Unless you hit the `Enter` key nothing happens as System.in is line buffered so you must have hit it at at the end.

Comment: Warning: a character is NOT a byte...

Comment: @fge yes, yes, I know, but in this case I save in a byte[], just to stress the point, that the read() method belongs to a byte stream class. Thank you all the same for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you press enter, your computer passes the system-dependent line terminator/separator character(s) to the input stream/console to let it know that you pressed enter and that the inputted line is ready for processing. Your input stream is reading those characters.

On Windows, those characters are `"\r\n"` (a carriage return character followed by a newline character). For *nix systems it's `'\n'` only, so on a Mac or a Linux machine you'd see `"You have read 1 bytes."`

I'm not sure whether it is possible to actually read in 0 characters. You can close the input stream, but that *might* cause a `NoSuchElementException` or something like that instead. Not sure what CTRL+D and/or EOF would do either.

Comment: If I pass 1234567890, the output will be: "You have read 10 bytes" and "You wrote: 1234567890", in this case, where the \r\n go?

Comment: @ardavirus They're sitting in the input stream. If you tried to read more data you'll pull those characters next.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, now all makes sense. I was thinking my data array and the input stream as the same thing...big rookie mistake!!!

Comment: @ardavirus Glad I could help! This is actually something that's pretty easy to forget (or at least it is for me), so don't feel too bad. I usually avoid it by making a habit of reading entire lines at once so I never have to deal with those characters in the first place.